# Simple markup parsing using parsekit

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsekit

I am trying to parse a really small subset of HTML markup.

```
PKSequence *parrser = [PKSequence sequence];
[parrser add:[PKSymbol symbolWithString:@"<title>"]];   
PKWord *word = [PKWord word];
[word setAssembler:self selector:@selector(workOnWordAssembly:)];
[parrser add:word];
[parrser add:[PKSymbol symbolWithString:@"</title>"]];

PKAssembly *result = [parrser bestMatchFor:[PKTokenAssembly assemblyWithString:@"<title>teeest</title>"]];


-(void)workOnWordAssembly:(PKAssembly *)a {
        NSLog(@"We entered this");
}
```

but `workOnWordAssembly` is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here. Make sure you are using [head of trunk on google code](https://code.google.com/p/parsekit/).

1. Assembler callbacks [now have two arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647734/34934).
2. By default, the string `<title>` will not be tokenized as a single Symbol token. That would be one `<` Symbol token, one `title` Word token and one `>` Symbol token. You could configure that behavior, however.

Please read the documentation on [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com), particularly the [tokenization docs](http://parsekit.com/tokenization.html) to understand how tokenization in ParseKit works.

---

Here's what's missing to accomplish your basic task above. However, I'm not sure this is the best approach for a real world task. I think reading the docs mentioned above would help explain that.

```
PKTokenizer *t = [PKTokenizer tokenizerWithString:@"<title>foobar</title>"];
[t.symbolState add:@"<title>"];
[t.symbolState add:@"</title>"];

PKAssembly *a = [PKTokenAssembly assemblyWithTokenizer:t];

PKSequence *p = [PKSequence sequence];

[p add:[PKSymbol symbolWithString:@"<title>"]]; 

PKWord *word = [PKWord word];
[word setAssembler:self selector:@selector(parser:didMatchWord:)];
[p add:word];

[p add:[PKSymbol symbolWithString:@"</title>"]];

PKAssembly *result = [p bestMatchFor:a];
```

---

```
-(void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchWord:(PKAssembly *)a {
        NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you recommend creating a parser from a grammar for a real word task?